# How to change USERNAME And PASSWORD of MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have installed **MySQL Server 5.0** on my machine **(Windows-7 OS)**.

My existing USERNAME And PASSWORD for MySQL is root. I want to change both USERNAME And PASSWORD.

Many people have asked this question before but none was useful for me. Can anybody
tell me **HOW and from WHERE** can I change it?

Comment: This would need a query to be solved so i think the question is in rifght place?

Comment: You should have ask the question to Google : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/passwords.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just execute this query from mysql console:

```
 UPDATE mysql.user SET user='newusername',
 password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE user='root';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Nice this one works excellent

Comment: Renaming the root is debatable. Here's a great answer on another stackexchange community : http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6785/beneficial-to-rename-mysql-root-user

Comment: the password column is now called authentication_string so authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpassword')

Comment: you also may need to restart mysql server after this

Comment: No you don't need to, because FLUSH PRIVILEGES; command will update users properly

Answer (score 8):

**Instructions**

1. Click the Windows "Start" button and type "cmd" in the search text box. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Windows command line.
2. Type "mysql" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start the MySQL command line utility. Using the MySQL command line, you can update the tables on the database.
3. Type the following SQL code to update the root user:
   `UPDATE mysql.user SET user='newuser' WHERE User = 'root';`
   Change `newuser` with the value you want to use in place of `root`
4. Type the following SQL code to change the default user's password:
   `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = password('pass') WHERE User = 'newuser';`
   Replace `pass` with the new password, and replace `newuser` with the name of the user you set up in the previous step.

[Read more](http://www.ehow.com/how_8517658_change-default-mysql-username-password.html#ixzz2nLQRovoT)

[To change UserName and Password from mysql console](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/)

Comment: Nice step by step! Upvote!

Comment: @KayNelson Thank You, this encourages me

Answer (score 4):

USE THIS CMD IN MYSQL CONSOLE OR CMD

**STEP** 1: `mysql> use mysql;`

**STEP** 2: `CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';`

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest to stay with a root user and change the password if you want. Having a root user is convenient and renaming it is debatable (see [this conversation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6785/beneficial-to-rename-mysql-root-user)). Plus, calling it 'root' is not that "unsecured" if you respect good practices (such as IP/hostname restriction).

Conclusion : change the root password and secure access to your server if you still feel unconfortable. Then, create another user with USERNAME as the login and PASSWORD as the password.

1. To change the root password (in a MySQL Console) :

   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURPASSWORDHERE') WHERE User='root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
2. To create a new user : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/create-user.html
3. If your root user has a lot of privileges you don't want to replicate manually to the newly created user, then using a stored procedure could be a good solution : [Copy user privileges between databases on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400185/copy-user-privileges-between-databases-on-the-same-server)

Answer (score 3):

There are special MySQL commands:

1. [RENAME USER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/rename-user.html)
2. [SET PASSWORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-password.html)

Answer (score 1):

I not sure if you can change the username, you could drop it and create antoher one instead but not sure if update is possible.

Login to the commandline promt.

Set the mysql database

```
USE mysql;
```

Create the new user first if `root` is your only username

```
CREATE USER 'newusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpass';
```

Then drop the old root

```
DROP user root;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-names.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-user.html