# Alter name from database USER using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, alter

I consulted the oficial doc from MYSQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html

But does not work.

I have to Alter the username from database User.

Example:

User database:

```
login: john password: 123
```

New name:

```
login: johny password:123
```

Is it possible?

Example in mysql panel:

[image]

If i change de Login name i can... All the privileges are maintained

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change USERNAME And PASSWORD of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562648/how-to-change-username-and-password-of-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

open mysql and enter into the database with your username(john) and password(123) -

now enter the following commands :

```
use mysql;

update user set User='johny'  where User='john';

flush privileges;
```

And if you also want to change the password then -

again enter into database with your username and password

now enter the following commands :

```
use mysql;

update user set PASSWORD=password("updated password")  where User='johny';

flush privileges;
```

Comment: Gives the comment: "You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. 0.00051 sec"